# Pandas read_csv load data with irregular rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Say I have csv data such as the following:

```
a
b,c
d,e,f
g,h
i
```

(Note the missing commas indicating empty values)

How can I load this into a DataFrame so that the empty values get filled with NaNs (or at least something), as seen below?

```
     0    1    2
0    a  NaN  NaN
1    b    c  NaN
2    d    e    f
3    g    h  NaN
4    i  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me for the above data:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

def add_delimiters(fpath, delimiter=','):

    s_data = ''
    max_num_delimiters = 0

    with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            s_data += line
            delimiter_count = line.count(delimiter)
            if delimiter_count > max_num_delimiters:
                max_num_delimiters = delimiter_count

    s_delimiters = delimiter * max_num_delimiters + '\n'

    return io.StringIO(s_delimiters + s_data)

pd.read_csv(add_delimiters('data.csv'))
```

Simply calling `pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)` throws a ParseError when tring to load the data. `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 2`

It seems that rather than needing to manually edit the data by adding extra delimiters to the first row, this should be the default behavior. Or at least there should be a flag that we can raise to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add `,,` to beginning of your file to make it like:

```
,,
a
b,c
d,e,f
g,h
i
```

Then it will read exactly like you imagined it should.

This is the output of `pd.read_csv('test.csv')`:

```
     Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2
0          a        NaN        NaN
1          b          c        NaN
2          d          e          f
3          g          h        NaN
4          i        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: I suspect you need a bit of python  work before to do it. what's happening when you reading  that file ? do you have an error? can you show us what's happening?

Comment: @Herc01 ```pd.read_csv('data'.txt', header=None)``` fails with a ParseError. ```pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None, sep='delimiter')``` loads all of the data as strings into the first column.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are you just bothered by the missing values  or the unnamed columns. it should works straight away if it is csv file. Then you just  have to fill the missing cells. Do not use the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', header=None)
```

you can fill the missing values yourself.This should work unless the data is a bit different.

Comment: Now this doesn't work for me. `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 2`

Comment: @mitchute are you having the same error message. I am  not able to experience your error from the sample of data  you have given. i just tried it and I read it perfectly